# Android Studio: check where the file is created in code

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on a complex Android Studio project, which creates many files and directories.

My question is: starting from a file or directory created, is there a command to search where the file is automatically created in the code?

E.g.: I have a `textFiles/text.txt` in emulator explorer... I want to find, starting from the file, where is the function `createText()` in the code that created the specifical file.

Comment: u mean files created on pc or phone?

Comment: On emulator...............

Comment: you can get the path of the saved directory from file object

Answer (score 4):

Press Ctrl + Shift + F and you will be able to search from whole project. In your case try to search createtext() or text.txt.

Comment: only have text.txt, and I don't know if it's created passing the title as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Make a complete search of `mkdir()` in whole solution, you will find the method where the directories are actually created. Then look for that methods usage for where its been called for creation of your specific file.(*Try debugging your code)

Answer (score 2):

Hit the shift key 3 times and begin typing the file name.